# JSQuery.load Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I have done a search around and found some similar questions, but nothing specificly solutionary to what I need.

I need to periodically refresh my Highchart so it pulls through updated data and displays accurate information to the user. The page is displayed on a TV that is left on all day for reporting purposes.

To save the nastiness of a periodic full page refresh I place each element on a different page and then load/refresh periodically with JQuery.load()

What I want to do then is continue that trend, placing the Highchart on a seperate page and peridodically pulling it through for a seamless updating process.

When I try and "load" the URL that contains the chart it brings through the heading but not the actual graph.

Do anybody know the best way to pull through a loaded graph? perhaps Ajax? but not 100% sure what I would need to use.

Thanks,

Ryan.

An example of the script that works on other elements:

```
var URL = '/technical/support-dashboard-swyx';
$('#tspeople').load(URL + ' #tscalls');
}

loadswyx();
setInterval(function() {
    loadswyx()
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Do you have any errors? One thing is important: load Highcharts lib once only, in the main file. There may be another issue, that Highcharts is interactive library, not static HTML content, so `load()` may be messing around. I would rather use `$.ajax()` to load only necessary data to be displayed, and then use Highcharts API to update data on the chart. In terms of performance and bandwidth, it's better to pass on only necessary data, not all other stuff (like all themes for Highcharts etc.).

Answer (score 0):

How about using iframe?
Then you should be able reload it with js using this code.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('youriframe');
iframe.src = iframe.src;
```

If you want to reload only data, which you have with ajax - use http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data

Comment: That is certainly one work around. Although I was trying to avoid iframes where possible to be honest. However, could it be the only way?

Comment: No. of course iframe isn't only one possible solution. It can help you if you want reload it from other pages easily. But there is another solution for ajax updating data for charts. You can also use something like $('#mychart').highcharts().get('id_of_series').setData(newJsonOfData); This method documented on link above.